# Is there a special form to send sms to ios12?

Tags: ios12

Apple iOS 12 can display an SMS verification code on your keyboard ( see [here](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/ios-12-makes-2fa-for-third-party-apps-websites-easy-with-security-code-autofill-from-sms-texts-0185186/) for example ).

If so, are there any special forms of sending sms?

Something like?

```
[Web Send]
[KB Liiv Bank] Authorization [445867]
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Please clarify your question. Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Tried to improve wording/formattig, and a link to more information. But I agree with the comments, you should have a look at the question yourself and give more details what exactly you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be some terms like 'code' or ‘security code’ in the SMS containing the OTP. That can be read by iOS.

Please check the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/204/) for more details.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Is there a technology link to Apple that can validate your answer?

Comment: Edited with screenshot of WWDC video